# Build a Q object for sql view

Tags: java, querydsl, sql-view

I'm using querydsl in my spring-boot application.

Is it possible to build Q object for my sql- views?

When i'm running "mvn install" command Q objects are created only for tables and not for views.

**pom**

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
         <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
         <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
------
    <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                                    <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
       </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a class represents the view data with @Entity annotation and after running "mvn install" command the Q object will be created.